# What does 9 3/4 mean

Tags: measure-expressions

[image: screenshot of a book page]

What does onto platform 9 3/4 mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the original platform 9 3/4 is from the first book in the [Harry Potter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter) series, where author J.K. Rowling writes a story about witches and wizards that live in our modern world. It’s deliberately nonsensical:

Train platforms are, for rather obvious reasons only numbered by whole numbers (unless a totally different naming system is used).

So Platform 9 3/4 only makes sense in a magical world, where the general rules of logic can be ignored. The author uses the “absurd” number to emphasize how different the magic world is in comparison to the “Muggle” (non-magical) world. And the entrance to the hidden platform, where the train to the magic school leaves, is indeed between platforms 9 and 10.

So the leaflet offers a studio tour that includes the stage of the “platform 9 3/4” for the Harry Potter film series.

Comment: A side question: how do you pronounce 9 3/4?

Comment: @dan I'm no Harry Potter fan so I may not know how to pronounce this special platform, but I would pronounce it as "nine and three quarters." Some might also say "nine and three fourths." If the context were mathematics (in which case it would probably be written as 9.75), I would say "nine point seven five."